# Canvas rotate resets scale

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have video and canvas which has transformed video:

```
<video id="v" controls loop autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="file:///clip01-sound.mp4"
        type=video/mp4>
```

Canvas received images from video:

```
function draw(video, context, w, h) {
    if (video.paused || video.ended) return false;
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
    setTimeout(function () {
        draw(video, context, w, h);
    }, 0);
}
```

I have 2 button: rotate and scale

here's code:

```
function makeRotate() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var oldW = canvas.width;
    var oldH = canvas.height;
    canvas.width = oldH;
    canvas.height = oldW;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.translate(canvas.width, 0);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
}

function makeScale() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
```

If I click rotate button and scale then everything is OK.
But if I press scale which works OK but then rotate I receive rotated video but scale is reseted to 1.

What's wrong with my code or it's default behavior of rotate function. If yes how can I change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing canvas reset its context, so if you dont apply the scale after resizing the canvas, its scale will be 1, 1.